# What did Rajneesh/Osho mean by "all enlightened beings are navel-centered"?

Tags: enlightenment

I am quoting from memory.  This was in response to a question about J Krishnamurti and he said "all enlightened beings are navel -centered, but Krishnamurti uses his head for expression".

Comment: https://youtu.be/ytTvxZwTyCI

Comment: Is Osho a Hindu guru? If not, this question is off-topic.

Comment: actually "enlightenment" is off-topic to the board, with very few exceptions.

Comment: @sv. He had written commentary on Vijnānabhairav tantra a Kashmiri Shaivism text without knowing anything about Kashmiri Shaivism. I think writing commentary on a Hindu text might make him Hindu although he never said he is Hindu. His philosophy was very close to Advait Vedanta.

Comment: @Rohit. If he never considered himself a Hindu, then any questions about him or his philosophy might be off-topic here. Any questions/classifications on his commentaries on Hindu scripture is still on-topic, IMO.

Comment: whats up, @sv.?  got up on the wrong side of the bed today? :-)

Comment: LOL, no, my brain is working ok. I think Jiddu Krishnamurti's philosophy is also off-topic here. Wiki says: "Krishnamurti said he had no allegiance to any nationality, caste, religion, or philosophy." Wasn't sure about Osho, so I asked.

Comment: You would be hard put to find claims of being a Hindu from Ramana, Ramakrishna and so forth.

Comment: Osho is a failed pseudo guru. His quotes may or may not have truth or scriptural-basis.